# The application requires assembly Oracle.DataAccess version 1.102.5.0 to be installed

Tags: oracle, vba

I have a pretty old program that has been programmed in Visual basic. Now ive updated my system from Windows XP to windows 7 (yeah i know my company is late).

Now when i try to run the installer for the program i get the following error:

[image]
I'm not really sure what to do and was hoping that some of you guys could guide me the way or push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODP.NET 1.x is available only till Oracle 10.2 (herein 1.**102**). **1.** refers to version of Microsoft .NET Framework.

Either your old program must refer to ODP.NET 2.0 (or higher) or you have to install an old Oracle Client not newer than release 10.2. In setup you have to enable "Oracle Data Provider for .NET"

Comment: How do i force my program to refer to ODP.NET 2.0

Comment: You define this in the program code. Either you have the source code or you have to ask the vendor of your tool.